Using fgets() in a for loop in C
Consider my following code:
int main() {
    int letter_count=4;
    char tempstring[6];
    char userStrings[4][4];
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){

        fgets(tempstring,letter_count+1,stdin);

        tempstring[strcspn(tempstring, "\n")] = 0;

        strcpy(userStrings[i],tempstring);

        printf("\n%s found from %d\n",userStrings[i],i);

}
    return 0;
}

Now, what I am trying to do is: I want the user to input 4 words. Here, fgets() caputures these inputs. So, whenever, I try to input something smaller than 4 words, say foo and press enter the output is:
foo found from 0
But, whenever, I enter something of 4 words or more than that, it becomes unexpected. Consider, I input foil and press enter, this is what happens:
foil found from 0

 found from 1

Why is there a line  found from 1. The string tempstring has somewhat received a whitespace from the user input and the loop has advanced by one step, which should not have been the case. What I anticipate is, since fgets() receives more than five characters from user, it advances the loop once. Is there any way, I just want fgets() to receive exactly four letters or less and let the loop run only once?
I may try scanf() and gets(), but they cannot limit the size of user input. Any suggestions would gladly help me. Thanks.

You have a memory error.  char userStrings[4][4] can store four strings of 3 characters each (3 plus 1 terminating null character).  foil is a 4-character string, and requires 5 to store (4 + 1 terminating null character).  And why are you limiting your strings to just 3 (or 4) characters?

I can extend that to avoid Buffer Overflow. I will try...

But even I change to char userStrings[5][5];, the same logical error pops up. What to do then @TomKarzes

You have told fgets that the buffer it is writing to can only hold 5 characters.  So fgets will only read up to four bytes from the input stream.  If the input is foil\n, then the first call to fgets will read foil, and the 2nd call will read \n.  If you want to consume a full line, you need to check if the final character written by fgets is a newline.

Please try as bellow:
int main() {
    int letter_count = 4;
    char tempstring[256]; // Assume a large enough buffer to hold the input line
    char userStrings[4][5]; // 4 chars + null

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (fgets(tempstring, sizeof(tempstring), stdin) != NULL) {
            //Remove the '\n' if present
            tempstring[strcspn(tempstring, "\n")] = 0;

            if (strlen(tempstring) > letter_count) {
                tempstring[letter_count] = '\0'; // Truncate to four characters
            }
            strcpy(userStrings[i], tempstring);
            printf("\n%s found from %d\n", userStrings[i], i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


tempstring: Assuming a sufficiently large buffer (256 characters in this case) to accommodate the long lines that may input.
the string is truncated by overwriting the fifth character (index 4) with a null terminator (\0).


Here, if I input foiler, I just want foil to be captured and prune the remaining er. But that does not happen. Both foil and er is taken as different inputs and the loop advances by 2 instead of 1.

Code without explanation is not a good answer.

By the way, thanks @hello_user, I somehow managed to code myself the rest.

Note: if (strlen(tempstring) > letter_count) not needed.  tempstring[letter_count] = '\0'; is sufficient.
